# Reduce Shipping Cost if Cart is over $100

Tags: shipping

I want to offer the customer (if they spend over $100):

1. Free standard shipping
2. Express shipping, but instead of the normal $11, bring the price down to $5

How can I do the second part?

Comment: Express shipping  - is it table rates?  Have you tried any shipping rules modules?

Answer (score 0):

You can offer free standard shipping over 100$ using the free carrier.

Then set up table rates to have a rule that says when price >$100 set Express Shipping to be $5, otherwise set to $11.

The Matrixrates extension (which is totally free) will support all this in one, its just an enhancement of Tablerates that allows multiple shipping methods to be shown in Magento, its very easy to set up in there.